# "Install this third-party software" - safe for my system or questionable?

Tags: system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu atm and it asks me if I want to "Install this third-party software."

I assume it is safe to check this box and allow it to do this, but before I blindly do so I thought I'd ask. I searched google, and surprisingly nothing came up.

Answer (score 1):

That is up to you and whether you trust the developers of the third-party software. It simply letting you know that it is third-party software. It is not saying it is safe to install it, nor that it is unsafe to install it.

I would be surprised if there were any issues with it at all, but I'm certainly not going to guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

The third party software checkbox during the Ubuntu installation proceedure is used to add in some proprietary drivers and software, all files included in valid ubuntu installation discs are safe, just make sure you download Ubuntu from trusted sources. It's good that you asked though, that's a great way to approach any software installation.

Answer (score -1):

When you add a PPA repository you have to do it with add-ppa-repository "ppa name" command, example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pidgin-developers/ppa
```

If you already added it and see a message indicating a missing key number you can run:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com "key"
```

Comment: the enquirer is asking what the effect of selecting the "Install this third-party software" is (the checkbox you can select at the start of a Ubuntu installation). This has nothing to do with adding repositories.